# How to list only .doc or .xls files with the Windows dir command in the cmd window?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

When using:

```
dir *.doc
```

all files that have suffixes .docx, .docm, .doct, and .doc files are listed.

When using:

```
dir *.xls
```

all files that have suffixes .xlsx, .xlsm, and .xls files are listed.

Is there a way to use the dir command in the command prompt to only list files with the .doc extension?   Or only those with the .xls extension?  In other words prevent the results from including .docx, .docm, .xlsx, .xlsm, etc...

Comment: `dir *.doc *.xls` or `dir c:\folder\*.doc c:\folder\*.xls`. `Del` also supports multiple file specs the same way.

Comment: @Noodles - I think what wants is for docx file to -not- be included in the list.

Comment: Docx will have a short name of doc.

Comment: It's not finding docx, it's finding the shortname doc. See `dir /x`.

Comment: `dir /b *.doc | findstr /v /I "docx docm"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `findstr` to identify filenames ending with ".doc" an no other letters.

```
dir /s /b *.doc | findstr /I /E "\.doc"
```

Comment: a file with extension `.docdoc` would also be shown. (`findstr` treats the dot as "any char". Avoid with `findstr /e /i /c:".doc"` or `findstr /e /i "\.doc"`

Comment: @Stephan - Yes, I forgot that Microsoft was treating the string as a regex. That was not expected from the Microsoft I have always known for so many years.